# Pandas - calculating hourly mean rolling 10 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, rolling-computation

I have a dataset called `df` which have the following columns:

1. `city` - city for which the precipitation is calculated
2. `event_timestamp` - timestamp at which the precipitation was calculated
3. `precipitation` - value of the precipitation

I used the following code to calculate the nearest 10 minute mark from the `event_timestamp` column:

```
df["ten_ts"] = df["event_timestamp"].dt.floor("10 min")
```

*Objective*:
**Now, I want to calculate the past 1 hour mean of precipitation from every 10 minute point. In other words, with the window size of 1 hour, moving 10 minutes at each step and calculating mean of precipitation within that window. I want to do this separately for every city.**

I was not able to get my head around it. I tried following but it's not giving the right results for obvious reason:

```
df.groupby(["city", "ten_ts"]).rolling('1h', on='event_timestamp')["precipitation_1h"].mean().reset_index()
```

I also tried using the conventional approach of `for` loops but that was very slow and killing the kernel now and then.

Any way we can accomplish this in pandas and in a time efficient manner?

Edit:
sample data:

```
 city   event_timestamp        precipitation    ten_ts
0   A   2021-10-20 00:17:00.883183  0.316872    2021-10-20 00:10:00
1   A   2021-10-20 00:31:00.883183  1.159092    2021-10-20 00:30:00
2   A   2021-10-20 00:35:00.883183  0.541236    2021-10-20 00:30:00
3   A   2021-10-20 00:43:00.883183  0.152659    2021-10-20 00:40:00
4   A   2021-10-20 01:02:00.883183  1.943939    2021-10-20 01:00:00
5   A   2021-10-20 01:08:00.883183  0.493529    2021-10-20 01:00:00
6   A   2021-10-20 01:18:00.883183  0.164618    2021-10-20 01:10:00
7   A   2021-10-20 01:41:00.883183  0.710624    2021-10-20 01:40:00
8   A   2021-10-20 01:52:00.883183  3.546142    2021-10-20 01:50:00
9   A   2021-10-20 02:03:00.883183  3.177256    2021-10-20 02:00:00
10  A   2021-10-20 02:10:00.883183  0.185931    2021-10-20 02:10:00
11  A   2021-10-20 02:14:00.883183  2.581290    2021-10-20 02:10:00
12  A   2021-10-20 02:19:00.883183  0.393250    2021-10-20 02:10:00
13  A   2021-10-20 02:31:00.883183  0.189209    2021-10-20 02:30:00
14  A   2021-10-20 02:54:00.883183  1.134576    2021-10-20 02:50:00
15  A   2021-10-20 03:02:00.883183  1.449518    2021-10-20 03:00:00
16  A   2021-10-20 03:17:00.883183  0.756092    2021-10-20 03:10:00
17  A   2021-10-20 03:38:00.883183  0.620969    2021-10-20 03:30:00
18  A   2021-10-20 03:51:00.883183  0.119324    2021-10-20 03:50:00
19  A   2021-10-20 04:20:00.883183  0.937305    2021-10-20 04:20:00
20  B   2021-10-20 00:17:00.883183  0.168311    2021-10-20 00:10:00
21  B   2021-10-20 00:31:00.883183  0.681990    2021-10-20 00:30:00
22  B   2021-10-20 00:35:00.883183  1.699022    2021-10-20 00:30:00
23  B   2021-10-20 00:43:00.883183  0.871516    2021-10-20 00:40:00
24  B   2021-10-20 01:02:00.883183  1.226779    2021-10-20 01:00:00
25  B   2021-10-20 01:08:00.883183  0.266825    2021-10-20 01:00:00
26  B   2021-10-20 01:18:00.883183  2.164368    2021-10-20 01:10:00
27  B   2021-10-20 01:41:00.883183  0.906754    2021-10-20 01:40:00
28  B   2021-10-20 01:52:00.883183  0.447001    2021-10-20 01:50:00
29  B   2021-10-20 02:03:00.883183  0.945931    2021-10-20 02:00:00
30  B   2021-10-20 02:10:00.883183  0.847911    2021-10-20 02:10:00
31  B   2021-10-20 02:14:00.883183  0.134165    2021-10-20 02:10:00
32  B   2021-10-20 02:19:00.883183  0.286801    2021-10-20 02:10:00
33  B   2021-10-20 02:31:00.883183  3.113202    2021-10-20 02:30:00
34  B   2021-10-20 02:54:00.883183  0.168888    2021-10-20 02:50:00
35  B   2021-10-20 03:02:00.883183  0.596178    2021-10-20 03:00:00
36  B   2021-10-20 03:17:00.883183  0.993776    2021-10-20 03:10:00
37  B   2021-10-20 03:38:00.883183  0.142311    2021-10-20 03:30:00
38  B   2021-10-20 03:51:00.883183  0.506697    2021-10-20 03:50:00
39  B   2021-10-20 04:20:00.883183  0.125891    2021-10-20 04:20:00
```

Edit 2:
From Riley's idea, the below works as a solution:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["city", "ten_ts"]).agg({'precipitation': ['sum', 'count']}).reset_index()
df2.columns = ["city", "ten_ts", "ppt_sum", "ppt_count"]
df3 = df2.groupby("city").rolling('1H', on="ten_ts")[["ppt_sum", "ppt_count"]].sum().reset_index()
df3["avg_ppt"] = df3["ppt_sum"] / df3["ppt_count"]
```

Comment: can you give us some data to play with?

Comment: added the sample data

Comment: I think I would try 1) group by ten_ts and sum precipitation 2) group by ten_ts and count 3) apply 1 hour rolling to sum and count  4) divide the rolling sum by the rolling count

Comment: @Riley, thanks for the idea. I have added a workaround solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that at least *ten_ts* column is of *DateTime* type.
If it is not the case, start from converting it to *DateTime*.

Then define 2 functions:

1. A function to count the mean precipitation from the current group of rows (*grp*),
   for the last hour before the Timestamp "to" (*tsTo*):

   ```
   def cntMean(grp, tsTo):
       return grp[grp.ten_ts.between(tsTo - pd.Timedelta(60, 'T'), tsTo)].precipitation.mean()
   ```
2. A function to process the current group of rows (*grp*), i.e. to compute a partial
   result for this group:

   ```
   def procGrp(grp):
       return pd.DataFrame([(ts, cntMean(grp, ts))
           for ts in pd.date_range(grp.ten_ts.min(), grp.ten_ts.max(), freq='10T')],
           columns=['Time', 'MeanPrecip'])
   ```

And the actual computation involves only a **single**, although
a bit chained instruction:

```
result = df.groupby('city').apply(procGrp)\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Note that *apply* returns a DataFrame with a MultiIndex. The first level is the *city* and
the second - the original index of each partial result.

So the "post-processing" steps are:

- first: drop the level 1 index,
- second: convert the only index level left (*city*) to a "regular" column.

Comment: I think this approach is similar to the `for` loop approach as we are using apply. For the actual data I have, there are around 80 cities and over a month of data which makes it computationally very expensive to use for loop or apply. I tried the solution but it is again more time than it should.